# is this a rose quartz

Tags: crystals

[image][image][image][image]
pink quartz looking stone 19 pounds found in a vehicle in new york state

Comment: Judging only from the picture, it almost certainly is rose quartz.

Comment: Please add more information following [this guide](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/125/725).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is rose quartz. There are a number of mines in eastern New York near Vermont where rose quartz been found. Massive rose quartz can occur in granitic pegmatites.  I could not google to find images of any massive rose quartz from the northeastern United States but it is very similar in appearance to the rose quartz from Black Hill of South Dakota.  The rose quartz deposits from the Black Hills are the largest on earth and the material is sold world-wide.  Locally here in Ohio, I know of the landscaping company that has bulk rose quartz for sale.

You're specimen might be local to New York but might also be from elsewhere.

See [Mindat.org](https://www.mindat.org/min-3456.html)

Comment: thank you we in central new york i wish the camera could pick up the colors better it is really pink in color thank you for your help